# When can you use the pipeline operator for conditional arguments? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, operator-keyword, pipeline

I have the following line in my code:

```
var cart = $("#dynamo_shop_window .dynamo_content tbody .shop_cart").html();
```

However, I want the value of `cart` to be an empty string if there are no matching elements on the page, i.e:

```
!$("#dynamo_shop_window .dynamo_content tbody .shop_cart").size();
```

If this is the case, `var cart = null;`, well according to Chrome's developer tools anyway.

To give it the empty string value, is there any reason why I should use `cart = cart !== null ? cart : '';` after the above code instead of replacing the above code with:

```
var cart = $("#dynamo_shop_window .dynamo_content tbody .shop_cart").html() || '';
```

The `.html()` will never return `0` or any other `false` related statements.

Comment: I'm not looking for a workaround, but a reason **not** to use `||`.

Comment: It's actually pipe, not pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. The double pipe operator falls through to the right-hand side whenever there's a **falsey** value on the left-hand side, so one of `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0` or `""`.

If, in all those cases, you want `cart` to be `""`: go for it. Use `||`.

Comment: It returns `null`, not `undefined` `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cartVal = ($(".shop_cart").html().length > 0) ? $.trim($(".shop_cart").html()) : "";
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do the same, if I understood your question:

```
var cart = "";
if($("#dynamo_shop_window .dynamo_content tbody .shop_cart")){
    cart = $("#dynamo_shop_window .dynamo_content tbody .shop_cart").html();
}
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but I would guess because you should never make the exact same 2 jquery lookups in a row like that. Always cache the result the first time.